# Content Explanation Of: /proc/fs/ext4/device_name/mb_groups

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I've been wondering, what are the explanation of the columns in the `/proc/fs/ext4/device_name/mb_groups` file. The columns are:

```
#group: free frags first [ 2^0 2^1 2^2 2^3 2^4 2^5 2^6 2^7 2^8 2^9 2^10 2^11 2^12 2^13 ]
```

What's the meaning of every column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file contains information on the buddy group cache of that specific disk and it's useful for the fragmentation status of said disk.

The fields which I found are for a slightly different output, but at least it's a little more info.:

```
#group: free free frags first pa [ 2^0 2^1 2^2 2^3 2^4 2^5 2^6 2^7 2^8 2^9 
 2^10 2^11 2^12 2^13] 
#group number
Available blocks in the group
Blocks free on a disk
Number of free fragments
First free block in the group
Number of preallocated chunks (not blocks)
A series of available chunks of different sizes
```

I got my info from [here](https://jira.hpdd.intel.com/browse/LUDOC-148) and [here](http://build.whamcloud.com/job/lustre-manual/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/lustre_manual.xhtml#idp8394512)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't looking for a very deep explanation anyhow!